# Why is the sampling distribution of variance a chi-squared distribution?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, sampling, sample-size, chi-squared-distribution

**The statement**

The sampling distribution of the sample variance is a chi-squared distribution with degree of freedom equals to $n-1$, where $n$ is the sample size (given that the random variable of interest is normally distributed).

[Source](http://www.csus.edu/indiv/j/jgehrman/courses/stat50/samplingdists/7samplingdist.htm#samplevariance)

**My intuition**

It kinda makes intuitive sense to me 1) because a chi-square test looks like a sum of square and 2) because a Chi-squared distribution is just a sum of squared normal distribution. But still, I don't have a good understanding of it.

**Question**

**Is the statement true? Why?**

Comment: The initial statement is false in general (it's false for two separate reasons). What is your source (your link is missing), and what does it actually say?

Comment: My question also comes to reaction to a question-answer in a introductory stats class for which the access is protected. The question is "What distribution is the sampling distribution of variance in wing length in flies?" and the answer is "Chi-squared distribution"

Comment: The quoted statement in your first comment is still false in general. The comment at the end of the source is true (with the necessary assumptions): "*when samples of size n are taken from a normal distribution with variance $\sigma^2$, the sampling distribution of the $(n-1)s^2/\sigma^2$ has a  chi-square distribution with n-1 degrees of freedom.*" ... The answer to the question in your second comment will also be false -- unless, I suppose, someone has shown that wing length is normally distributed. (What basis could there be for asserting this to be true?)

Comment: So let's assume the wings are normally distributed, then the sampling distribution of $(n-1)s^2/\sigma^2$ would be chi-squared distributed. Why is it so?

Comment: Are you aware that a sum of squares of $k$ iid N(0,1) random variables is chi-squared with $k$ d.f.? Or is that the part you seek proof of?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[I'll assume from the discussion in your question that you're happy to accept as fact that if $Z_i, i=1,2,\ldots,k$ are independent identically distributed $N(0,1)$ random variables then $\sum_{i=1}^{k}Z_i^2\sim \chi^2_k$.]

Formally, the result you need follows from [Cochran's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem#Sample_mean_and_sample_variance).
 (Though it can be shown in other ways)

Less formally, consider that if we knew the population mean, and estimated the variance about it (rather than about the sample mean): $s_0^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\mu)^2$, then $s_0^2/\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{X_i-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}Z_i^2$,  ($Z_i=(X_i-\mu)/\sigma$) which will be $\frac{1}{n}$ times a $\chi^2_n$ random variable.

The fact that the sample mean is used, instead of the population mean ($Z_i^*=(X_i-\bar{X})/\sigma$) makes the sum of squares of deviations smaller, but in just such a way that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(Z_i^*)^2\,\sim\chi^2_{n-1}$ (about which, see Cochran's theorem). That is, rather than $ns_0^2/\sigma^2\sim \chi^2_n$ we now have $(n-1)s^2/\sigma^2\sim\chi^2_{n-1}$.

Comment: @Glen_b Can you give a reference for other proofs on this fact? I really want to know it.

Comment: Which of several facts are you after proof of?

Comment: @Glen_b The only two methods besides Cochran-Madow Theorem of proving this fact that the sample variance and the sample mean is statistiacally independent with a chi-square distribution are:(1)Scheffe's canonical basis(Scheffe,1959)(2)Cumulant methods(Or mgfs, which is equivalent to it). If you know more methods, I really want to know them.

Comment: One more comment I want to add is that altough sample mean is used, but sometimes we want a fixed power independent of the fixed  variance, this method is replaced by Stein's two-stage method(1949).

Comment: What I don't get about this answer, is that $\bar X$ is not independent of all the $X_i's$, so how can we apply Cochran's theorem? it says that they all need to be independent.

Comment: $\bar{X}$ is independent of $X_i-\bar{X}$ in this circumstance

Comment: @Glen_b: Thanks, I have added the proof [here](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/norm-chi2).

Comment: In practice one often uses the Bessel corrected estimator of variance, i.e. with $n-1$ normalization, - what is the distribution of the estimate in that case? Is it $\chi^2_{n-2}$?  Thank you

Comment: The $n-1$ denominator on $s^2$ (i.e. the Bessel corrected sample variance $s^2_{n-1}$) is unbiased when $\mu$ is estimated by $\bar{x}$; this is exactly what is being discussed in both the question and the last paragraph of the answer. Which is to say, that's the thing that's distributed as a multiple of $\chi^2_{n-1}$. If you didn't use the Bessel-correction, it would have the same d.f. on the chi-squared but a different scale-factor in the multiple.