# Variance of the $\hat{\sigma}^2$ of a Maximum Likelihood estimator

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, variance, maximum-likelihood, random-variable

Given some normally distributed observations $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$

$\forall i\ x_i\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$

the ML estimator decides that the variance that maximizes the likelihood function is (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood#Iterative_procedures)):

$\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2$

Now, I am trying to find the variance of this estimation:

$\sigma^2_{\hat{\sigma}^2}=\operatorname{Var}[\hat{\sigma}^2]=\operatorname{Var}[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2]$

If we note that:
$\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i^2-2x_i\bar{x}+\bar{x}^2) \\   
=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2-2\bar{x}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\bar{x}^2 \\
=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2-2\bar{x}^2+\bar{x}^2 \\
=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2-\bar{x}^2$

we have:

$\sigma^2_{\hat{\sigma}^2}=\operatorname{Var}[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2-\bar{x}^2]$

but I am stuck here since I think that $x_i$ and $\bar{x}$ are not independent in order to use the property that says that the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances.

Comment: This search may help: http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=variance+of+sample+variance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you know the famous result that if $X_1, \ldots, X_n \text{ i.i.d. } \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then
$$\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2 \sim \chi_{n - 1}^2?$$
It is also well-known that the variance of a $\chi_k^2$ random variable is $2k$.

An alternative treatment is to express the sample variance as a quadratic form of the random vector $\mathbf{X} = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ then apply the quadratic form variance formula.  See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/608674/variance-among-coordinates-of-multivariate-normal/608706#608706) for a solution to a slightly more general case.

Comment: I know about the second part about the variance of chi-squared distribution you are referring to but where does the first result come from? I mean, how can I prove it? Finally, what is the distribution of $X_i-\bar{X}$?

Comment: @KonstantinosKonstantinidis For one possible justification, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121662/why-is-the-sampling-distribution-of-variance-a-chi-squared-distribution