# Variance Among Coordinates of Multivariate Normal

Tags: variance, multivariate-normal-distribution

Sample $(X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n)^T\sim{\mathcal{N}(\textbf{0}, \Sigma)}$. What is the expected cross-sectional variance of $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)^T$? In other words, if
$$
S^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n \left(X_k - \bar{X}\right)^2\qquad\text{and}\qquad \bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n X_k,
$$
what is $E[S^2]$?

As an example, I'll show the relatively trivial two dimensional case. Suppose
$$(X_1, X_2)^T\sim{\mathcal{N}\left(\textbf{0}, \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_1^2 & \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 \\ \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2\end{pmatrix}\right)}.
$$
Then the cross-sectional mean is
$$
\bar{X} = \frac{X_1+X_2}{2}.
$$
Using the cross-sectional mean, the cross-sectional variance is
$$
S^2 = \frac{1}{2}\left(X_1 - \bar{X}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\left(X_2 - \bar{X}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{X_1 - X_2}{2}\right)^2
$$
Hence, the expected cross-sectional variance is
$$
E\left[S^2\right] = E\left[\left(\frac{X_1 - X_2}{2}\right)^2\right] = \frac{\sigma_1^2 - 2\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2+\sigma_2^2}{4}.
$$

Comment: Are you asking about how to compute the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ as a function of the individual variances $\sigma_i^2$ of $X_i$ for $i = 1,\dots,n$?

Comment: I'm not. I probably should of stuck closer to the original finance version. The covariance matrix is calculated across time, and we can treat it as a given. We're looking to calculate the cross-sectional variance at a particular time $t$.

Comment: Could you provide a definition of "cross-sectional variance" or of the "the random variable with actualizations..."?  One difficulty is that $(X_1,X_2)$ is a *bivariate* random variable. Its covariance is a $2\times 2$ matrix, not a number.  The value you give looks a bit like the variance of the *arithmetic mean,* $(X_1+X_2)/2,$ except the sign of $\rho$ is wrong.  And what distinction do you make between a *variance* (which is a numerical property of a random variable or distribution) and an "expected variance"?

Comment: Let's stick to the $2\times 2$ case for now. I think it should be clear from there. Suppose we sample one element from the bivariate normal above. Call it $(X_1, X_2)^T$. Then, for this particular sample, the cross-sectional mean would be $\bar{X} =(X_1+X_2)/2$, and the cross-sectional variance would be $(X_1 - \bar{X})^2/2 + (X_2 - \bar{X})^2/2 = (X_1 - X_2)^2/4$. Hence, the expected variance is $E[(X_1 -X_2)^2/4] = (\sigma_1^2 - 2\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 + \sigma_2^2)/4$. Does this help? My apologies for the confusing formulation.

Comment: That, at least, defines your terms: it looks like the cross-sectional variance is a particular (homogeneous) quadratic form and you wish to find its expectation.  That's a readily solvable problem.  Would you mind elevating the information in your comment to a prominent place in your post itself?  Welcome to CV, btw.  If you're unfamiliar with StackExchange communities, a couple of minutes reviewing our [help] might be of use to you.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at the help center, though I've added questions to other StackExchanges before. The question has been reworded to reflect my comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "variance" in the question refers to the formula given by

$$V(X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^2.$$

This is a *homogeneous quadratic form* with coefficients $v_{ij}$ given by

$$V(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n) = \sum_{i,j=1}^n v_{ij}\, X_iX_j.$$

By inspecting the formula for $V$ it is evident that

$$v_{ii} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2}$$

(one term from each of the right-hand parts of the formula) and for $i\ne j$

$$v_{ij} = -\frac{1}{n^2} X_iX_j$$

(the cross-products appearing solely in the right-hand term of the formula).

Because the expectations of all the $X_i$ are zero, $\Sigma_{ij} = \operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j) = E[X_iX_j].$  Consequently, linearity of expectation gives us the answer, which for convenience I will express in various equivalent forms:

$$\begin{aligned}
E\left[V(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)\right] &= \sum_{ij} v_{ij} E[X_iX_j] \\
&= \sum_{ij} v_{ij}\Sigma_{ij} \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i} \Sigma_{ii} -\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i,j} \Sigma_{ij} \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma) - \frac{1}{n^2}\mathbf 1^\prime \Sigma \mathbf 1.
\end{aligned}$$

FWIW, the second line is (a) the dot product of $V$ and $\Sigma$ considered as vectors of length $d^2$ and (b) according to the rules of matrix multiplication, can be expressed as $\operatorname{tr}(V^\prime\Sigma)=\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma^\prime V) = \operatorname{tr}(\Sigma V)$ *etc.* because $\Sigma$ is symmetric.  ($V$ can always be made symmetric by replacing every $v_{ij}$ by $(v_{ij}+v_{ji})/2.$)  It's helpful to have seen such matrix expressions before so you can understand what they really *mean* and where they come from.

---

The same technique serves to find the expectation of any form in a set of variables, whether homogenous or not, of any degree.  For quadratic forms like $V$ all we need to know is $\Sigma$ (it doesn't matter that the distribution is multivariate Normal).  For forms of higher degree, we need to know the higher multivariate moments.

Answer (score 8):

Based on your comment, you question can be clarified as follows:

> *If $(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \sim N_n(0, \Sigma)$, what is the expected value of the sample variance (before bias correction)*
> \begin{align}
> S^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n(X_i - \bar{X})^2? 
> \end{align}

There are many solutions to this classical problem. One that I like most is to express $S^2$ as a quadratic form of $\mathbf{X} = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, then apply the [quadratic form expectation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form_(statistics)#Expectation). As an exercise, you can verify that
\begin{align}
nS^2 = \mathbf{X}^T\Lambda\mathbf{X}, \tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\Lambda = I_{(n)} - n^{-1}ee^T$ and $e$ is an $n$-long column vector of all ones.  It then follows by the formula in the above link that
\begin{align}
E[S^2] =\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{tr}(\Lambda\Sigma)
=\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma) - \frac{1}{n^2}e^T\Sigma e. \tag{2}
\end{align}

With the representation $(1)$ and the Gaussian assumption, you can even ask for the variance of $S^2$, which follows from the [quadratic form variance formula in Gaussian case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form_(statistics)#Variance_in_the_Gaussian_case):
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(S^2) =\frac{2}{n^2}\operatorname{tr}(\Lambda\Sigma\Lambda\Sigma)
=\frac{2}{n^2}\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma^2) - 
\frac{4}{n^3}e^T\Sigma^2e 
+ \frac{2}{n^4}(e^T\Sigma e)^2. \tag{3}
\end{align}

Note that $(2)$ holds for any random vector with mean vector $0$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$.  $(3)$ additionally requires that the distribution to be Gaussian.  For similar, yet more technical problems, see [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/598863/distribution-of-mathbfx-top-mathbba-mathbfx-mathbfb-top-mathbf/598946#598946) and [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/598231/expected-squared-dot-product-between-iid-gaussian-vectors/598379#598379).