# Is there any white noise test that tests whether its variance is equal to a certain value $\sigma^2$ or not?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, white-noise

To my knowledge, all white noise tests are to test whether a process is a white noise or not. Is there any test in time or frequency domain, that test for a white noise, whether its variance is equal to a certain value $\sigma^2$ or not? Given a white noise process $X_1,\cdots, X_N$, I want to test $H_0$:
$$H_0: \sigma_X^2 =\sigma^2 \hspace{0.3cm}\text{vs}\hspace{0.3cm} H_1: \sigma_X^2 \neq \sigma^2$$

Comment: Have you looked up "variance test"?

Comment: The results at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121662 lead naturally to a simple, effective test.