# How to ge the Monte Carlo standard deviation of the empirical standard deviation?

Tags: standard-deviation, simulation, monte-carlo

The authors get the Monte Carlo standard deviation of the empirical standard deviation as follows.

[image]

My question is how to get the MCSE of the EmpSE?

---

For bias, the MCSE of $\frac{1}{n}\sum \hat{\theta}_i-\theta$ is just
$$
\sqrt{Var[\frac{1}{n}\sum \hat{\theta}_i-\theta]}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}Var[\hat{\theta}_1]}
$$
The estimate of the variance is just $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum(\hat{\theta}_i-\bar{\theta})^2$ where $\bar{\theta}=\frac{1}{n}\sum \hat{\theta}_i$.

But how to use this idea to get MCSE of EmpSE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please include proper citations. Online libraries make this very easy; for example Wiley has a citation tool (next to the wrench icon) which generates the following:

Morris, TP, White, IR, Crowther, MJ. Using simulation studies to evaluate statistical methods. *Statistics in Medicine*. 2019; 38: 2074–2102. https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.8086

The Monte Carlo simulations described in the paper are implemented in the *simsum* user-written command in Stata and the [rsimsum](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rsimsum/index.html) package in R.

---

Let's start with notation: We want to analyze the statistical properties of a proposed study (bias, power, etc.) so we simulate $n_{\text{sim}}$ replicates of a dataset and its analysis. The $i$th simulation produces an estimate $\hat{\theta}_i$ of a parameter $\theta$.

The Monte Carlo (MC) error formulas assume that the $\hat{\theta}_i$s are normally distributed [1], [2].

$$
\begin{aligned}
\hat{\theta}_i \sim \operatorname{Normal}\left(\theta+\operatorname{bias}, \operatorname{Var}(\hat{\theta})\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

We'll skip estimating the bias because your question is about the precision of the estimator $\hat{\theta}$, ie. the empirical standard error:

$$
\operatorname{EmpSE} = \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(\hat{\theta})}
$$

The estimate of the empirical SE is:

$$
\widehat{\operatorname{EmpSE}} = \sqrt{\widehat{\operatorname{Var}}(\hat{\theta})}
$$

This looks like a tautology; however, we don't know $\operatorname{Var}(\hat{\theta})$ but we can calculate $\widehat{\operatorname{Var}}(\hat{\theta})$ from the simulations. It's the *Estimate* in the second row of Table 6.

The Monte Carlo error (squared) of the estimate of the empirical SE is:

$$
\operatorname{Var}\left(\widehat{\operatorname{EmpSE}}\right) = \operatorname{Var}\left(\sqrt{\widehat{\operatorname{Var}}(\hat{\theta})}\right)
$$

That's right: We want to estimate the variance of a standard error estimator. The formula simplifies considerably because of the normality assumption.

Since the $\hat{\theta}_i$s are normal:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{(n_{\text{sim}}-1)\widehat{\operatorname{Var}}(\hat{\theta})}{\operatorname{Var}(\hat{\theta})} \sim \chi^2_{n_{\text{sim}}-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

This should look familiar: [Why is the sampling distribution of variance a chi-squared distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121662/why-is-the-sampling-distribution-of-variance-a-chi-squared-distribution) In a random sample $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ from a $\operatorname{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution, $(n-1)s^2/\sigma^2 \sim \chi^2_{n-1}$ where $s^2$ is the sample variance.

We know that the $\chi^2_{n_{\text{sim}}-1}$ distribution has mean $(n_{\text{sim}}-1)$ and variance $2(n_{\text{sim}}-1)$. We can use these properties to show that:

$$
\operatorname{Var}\left(\widehat{\operatorname{EmpSE}}\right) \approx \frac{\operatorname{Var}(\hat{\theta})}{2(n_{\text{sim}}-1)} \approx \frac{\widehat{\operatorname{Var}}(\hat{\theta})}{2(n_{\text{sim}}-1)}
$$

Take the square root to derive the formula for the Monte Carlo error of $\widehat{\operatorname{EmpSE}}$. It contains $\widehat{\operatorname{EmpSE}}$!

[1] Morris, TP, White, IR, Crowther, MJ. Using simulation studies to evaluate statistical methods. *Statistics in Medicine*. 2019; 38: 2074–2102. https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.8086 
[2] White IR. Simsum: Analyses of Simulation Studies Including Monte Carlo Error. *The Stata Journal*. 2010;10(3):369-385. https://doi.org/10.1177/1536867X1001000305

---

Here is my attempt to show that $\operatorname{Var}\left(\widehat{\operatorname{EmpSE}}\right) \approx \operatorname{Var}(\hat{\theta}) \left/ [2(n_{\text{sim}}-1)] \right. $.

I start by simplifying the notation: Let's show that $\operatorname{Var}\{S\} \approx \sigma^2 \left/ [2(n-1)] \right. $ where $S$ is the sample standard deviation of $n$ iid $\operatorname{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ random variables.

1. Multiply and divide by $\sigma^2/(n-1)$.
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   \operatorname{Var}\left\{S\right\}
   = \operatorname{Var}\left\{\left(\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\right)^{1/2}\right\} \frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}
   \end{aligned}
   $$
   We know that $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2$ is $\chi^2_{n-1}$ with variance $2(n-1)$. What can we say about the variance of $\left((n-1)S^2/\sigma^2\right)^{1/2}$?
2. Use the delta method to approximate the variance of $f(X) = X^{1/2}$. Not being strong at theory, I looked this up on the Wikipedia page about the [Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Approximating_the_variance_of_a_function).
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   \operatorname{Var}\left\{X^{1/2}\right\}
   \approx \operatorname{Var}\left\{X\right\}\left(\frac{1}{2\left(\operatorname{E}X\right)^{1/2}}\right)^2\\
   \end{aligned}
   $$
3. Plug in and simplify. In our case $X = (n-1)S^2/\sigma^2$ with mean $(n-1)$ and variance $2(n-1)$.
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   \operatorname{Var}\left\{S\right\}
   \approx 2(n-1)\left(\frac{1}{2(n-1)^{1/2}}\right)^2\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1} = \frac{\sigma^2}{2(n-1)}
   \end{aligned}
   $$

Comment: Thanks! But why do you think The Monte Carlo (MC) error formulas assume that the $\hat{\theta}_i$ are normally distributed is an assumption? Can we get asymptotic normal from the Central limit theorem?

Comment: It's a simplifying assumption. Reference [2] mentions another approach (doesn't rely on the CLT). The CLT is not particularly relevant. It's easy to make $n_{\text{sim}}$ large but it's the sample size $n_{\text{obs}}$ which matters for the $\theta_i$s. Asymptotics won't make the $\theta_i$s Normal unless $n_{\text{obs}}$ is large.

Comment: This doesn't mean of course that $n_{\text{obs}}$ has to be large for the $\theta_i$s to be reasonably Normal. It means that you can't compensate for planning for a small $n_{\text{obs}}$ in the experiment with a large  $n_{\text{sim}}$ in the MC simulation.