# Distribution of a quantity similar to the $t$ statistic

Tags: normal-distribution, t-test, z-score

Suppose I have samples $A$ and $B$ from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with unknown mean and variance.
The sample sizes are $n_A$ and $n_B$.
I construct two statistics:
$$t_A=\frac{\bar X_A-\mu}{s_A/\sqrt{n_A}}$$
and
$$t_{B/A}=\frac{\bar X_B-\mu}{s_A/\sqrt{n_A}}$$
where $\bar X$ is the sample mean $s$ is the sample standard deviation. Clearly, $t_A\sim t(n_A-1)$. I am interested in the distribution of $t_{B/A}$. Questions:

1. When $n_A=n_B=:n$, is it true that $t_{B/A}\sim t(n-1)$? I guess so because of the independence of sample mean and variance of a normal distribution.
2. When $n_A\neq n_B$, what is the distribution of $t_{B/A}$?

Comment: The question is related to event studies where $A$ would be the estimation window and $B$ the event window. What we may lack there is that the true variances corresponding to $A$ and $B$ coincide. A reference would be Corrado ["Event studies: A methodology review"](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1467-629X.2010.00375.x) (2011) p. 216-218.

Comment: I think different variances should work, too, see the edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As to 1., yes, indeed, as we have an independent ratio of a standard normal and the square root of a chi-square root divided by its d.f. (for details, see below, setting $n_B=n_A$).

As to 2., we have by [standard results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121662/why-is-the-sampling-distribution-of-variance-a-chi-squared-distribution) that
$$
\sqrt{n_B}(\bar{X}_B-\mu)/\sigma\sim N(0,1)
$$
and
$$
(n_A-1)\frac{s_A^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_{n_A-1}
$$
Write
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
t_{B/A}&=&\frac{\bar X_B-\mu}{s_A/\sqrt{n_A}}\\
&=&\frac{\sqrt{n_A}(\bar X_B-\mu)/\sigma}{\sqrt{\frac{s_A^2}{\sigma^2}}}\\
&=&\sqrt{\frac{n_A}{n_B}}\frac{\sqrt{n_B}(\bar X_B-\mu)/\sigma}{\sqrt{\frac{s_A^2}{\sigma^2}}}\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Again, like in 1.,
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n_B}(\bar X_B-\mu)/\sigma}{\sqrt{\frac{s_A^2}{\sigma^2}}}\sim t(n_A-1),
$$
so that
$$t_{B/A}\sim \sqrt{\frac{n_A}{n_B}}t(n_A-1),$$
a *scaled* or *non-standardized* t-distribution with scale parameter $\sqrt{n_A/n_B}$, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Location-scale_t_distribution.

Illustration (reset `nB <- nA` if you want to illlustrate 1., also note the code allows for differing variances, see edit below):

[image]

```
library(extraDistr)
nA <- 10
nB <- 20

mu <- 0
sigmaA <- 2
sigmaB <- 2

tstats <- function(){
  A <- rnorm(nA, mu, sigmaA)
  B <- rnorm(nB, mu, sigmaB)

  tAB <- sqrt(nA)*mean(B)/sd(A)
}

plot(density(replicate(20000, tstats())), col="green", lwd=2, xlim=c(-4,4))
xax <- seq(-4, 4, by=0.1)
lines(xax, dlst(xax, df=nA-1, sigma=sqrt((sigmaB^2*nA)/(sigmaA^2*nB))), col="darkgreen", lwd=2)
lines(xax, dt(xax, df=nA-1), col="red", lwd=2)
```

EDIT in response to the comment below the question:

If the variances differ as in $Var(A_i)=\sigma_A^2$ and $Var(B_i)=\sigma_B^2$, we would write
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
t_{B/A}&=&\frac{\bar X_B-\mu}{s_A/\sqrt{n_A}}\\
&=&\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2_B}{\sigma^2_A}}\frac{\sqrt{n_A}(\bar X_B-\mu)/\sigma_B}{\sqrt{\frac{s_A^2}{\sigma_A^2}}}\\
&=&\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2_Bn_A}{\sigma^2_An_B}}\frac{\sqrt{n_B}(\bar X_B-\mu)/\sigma_B}{\sqrt{\frac{s_A^2}{\sigma_A^2}}},
\end{eqnarray}
$$
again obtaining a scaled t with a different scaling factor.

Comment: Nice, thank you!

Comment: The case with different variances seems to require knowledge of the variances, as otherwise the test statistic is infeasible. Is that right? (Also, I have simplified the question relative to the referenced application, so just allowing the variances to be different is still not enough.)

Comment: You could still compute the test statistic, see the code, but for critical values you would need the standard deviations, although it seems you could estimate both consistently. That would then however not be an exact result anymore of course, though.